# Asual $.address - how to get rid of hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, url-rewriting

I'm using Asuals jquery plugin $.address

everything is working but the url still provides hash tags in it

```
$("#ulSideNav a").address(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href').replace("#/", '')
});
```

(returns "/suburl")

```
$.address.change(function(event){
    var uri = event.value;
    if(uri.length > 1){
        ajaxRequest(uri);
    }
});
```

Does an ajax request on changeing the url (not base url)

```
$('#ulSideNav a').click(function(e) {
    $("#ulSideNav").children().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass('active selected');
});
```

Switches the active state of the navbar

```
 http://BASEURL/#/suburl
```

This is what the url looks like in the end

so my question is => how to delete that hashtag

(maybe something with window.location, but all my tries failed)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
newurl=window.location.href.replace("#/", '')
console.log(newurl);
window.location.href=newurl;
```

Comment: i placed into "adress change" -> it generates a get request => overwrites ajax  (ajax call, then normal get)